# Google maps Marker icon padding between icon-fillColor and strokeColor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a Google map marker icon with padding between the icon-fillColor and the outer StrokeColor.

My Marker Code:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
id: i,
position: position,
label: {
    text: 'id',
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '16px',
},
map: map,
title: "My Title",
icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 15,
    fillColor: "#4A86FE",
    fillOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeColor:"red",
    rotation: 30
},
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,});
```

My Current OutPut: If you can see the Inner Blue circle and The Outer red are touching each other. I'm trying to code a white color between inner and outer. Check my expected output.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you ceate a custom that as a custom SVG icon?

Comment: The icon color will be dynamic, the label color, the label text, the colour.. pretty much everything is dynamic for each marker.. so it was complicated. :(

Comment: The label color, and label text of a marker are configurable (in the marker class).  You are limited in what you can control with a `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` (`fillColor`, `fillOpacity`, `strokeOpacity`, `strokeWeight` and `strokeColor`), you can't create that white band.  You could possibly try overlaying two icons or make a custom SVG icon (and a way to set the parameters you care about).  None of this is built in to the API.

Comment: I couldn't able to find such an example, any doc link to refer? im not sure SVG icon work for me but i like the overlaying two icons concept. Thanks. @geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (using two overlapping markers) should work, you can add additional parameters (or create an "options" object) to define the colors of the various pieces:

```
function makeComplexIcon(map, latLng, fillColor, stripeColor, outsideColor, title, id, label) {
  var bottom = new google.maps.Marker({
    zIndex: 10, // bottom
    id: id,
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: title,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 15,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 6,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeColor: outsideColor,
      rotation: 30
    },
  });
  var top = new google.maps.Marker({
    zIndex: 15, // top
    id: id,
    position: latLng,
    label: label,
    map: map,
    title: title,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 15,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeColor: stripeColor,
      rotation: 30
    },
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6x2rb91u/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -25.363882,
      lng: 131.044922
    }
  });

  var position = map.getCenter(),
    i = 10;
  makeComplexIcon(map, position, "#4A86FE", "white", "red", "My Title", i, {
    text: 'id',
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '16px',
  });
  makeComplexIcon(map, {
    lat: -27.6728168,
    lng: 121.6283098
  }, "green", "yellow", "orange", "W. Australia", 12, {
    text: 'id1',
    color: "blue",
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '16px',
  })
  makeComplexIcon(map, {
    lat: -30.0,
    lng: 136.2
  }, "black", "white", "black", "S. Australia", 14, {
    text: 'id2',
    color: "red",
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '16px',
  })
}

function makeComplexIcon(map, latLng, fillColor, stripeColor, outsideColor, title, id, label) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    zIndex: 10, // bottom
    id: id,
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: title,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 15,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 6,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeColor: outsideColor,
      rotation: 30
    },
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    zIndex: 15, // top
    id: id,
    position: latLng,
    label: label,
    map: map,
    title: title,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 15,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      fillOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeColor: stripeColor,
      rotation: 30
    },
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```